# Login based on additional params with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My customer want to split user into normal user & 3rd party user. That mean in table user may has 2 records with same email but have different value in is_party_user (normal user = false and vice versa).

I tried to solve problem with this [instruction](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Scope-login-to-subdomain)

but it not work (undefined method `is_party_user' for ActionDispatch::Request:0x00000007619250)

is there a way to identify which type of user then authenticate in SessionController#create?

in login params of 3rd user with has additional param :is_party_user = true

user.rb

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :encryptable, :registerable,
     :validatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :lockable,
     :timeoutable, :omniauthable, request_keys: [:is_party_user]

def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions warden_conditions
    where(:email => warden_conditions[:email], :is_party_user => warden_conditions[:is_party_user]).first
  end
```

giving me an error at self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options) (SessionController#creat)

```
undefined method `is_party_user' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00000008def2a8>
```

params

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxxx", "user"=>{"is_party_user"=>"1", "email"=>"user@abc", "password"=>"1234"}}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the parameter? Is it only for a redirect once the user logs in or is it for something else?

Comment: @elvinas to identify which type of user is trying to login

Comment: can you post actual code ie what you tried?

Comment: @kasperite updated

Comment: do you get same error if override `find_for_authentication` instead?

Comment: @kasperite same error

Comment: I'd suggest that 'is_party_user' is not something you'd want coming in from a client, but a value you'd persist on the user record, which you may use to instantiate a different type of user.